# Importing a SQLite3 dump back into the database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, import

I feel like this is a stupid question because it seems like common sense . . . but no google search I can put together seems to be able to give me the answer!

I know how to get data OUT of a sqlite3 database using the .dump command. But now that I have this ASCII file titled export.sqlite3.sql . . . I can't seem to get it back INTO the database I want.

My goal was to transfer the data I had in one rails app to another so I didn't have to take all sorts of time creating dummy data again . . . so I dumped the data from my first app, got rid of all the CREATE TABLE statements, and made sure my schema on my second app matches . . . now I just have to get it IN there.

Would anyone mind helping me out? And when you find a way, will you tell me what you plugged into the google, 'cause I am beating my head open with a spoon right now over what I thought would be an easy find.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
cat dumpfile.sql | sqlite3 my_database.sqlite
```

[This is modified from the sqlite3 getting started guide.](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)

Comment: Excellent answer.

At the risk of sounding like a broken record, this is useless use of cat. Redirection is the answer:

   sqlite3 my_database.sqlite < dumpfile.sql

You can also perform the entire operation in a pipeline:

   sqlite3 old_database.sqlite .dump | sqlite3 my_database.sqlite

Comment: I agree, I usually use it in the < form too. Just trying to be explicit. I actually modified the example in the documentation which is using zcat.

Comment: I recommend prepending "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF; PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;" to the dump file before running this.  This makes restores much faster.  Obviously these settings should not be OFF when actually *using* the restored database.

Comment: 60 MB, 220'000 rows, in 10 seconds with prepending "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF; PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;" thanks @Brian

Answer (score 56):

You didn't specify your operating system and while

```
sqlite3 my_database.sqlite < export.sqlite3.sql
```

will work for the unix flavors, it will not work for windows.

The inverse of the .dump command is the .read command.  The syntax would be

```
sqlite3> .read export.sqlite3.sql
```

Comment: unix flavors command not working.. did you restore using this?

Comment: yes, but be aware that the sqlite3> is not a unix command, it is the sqlite3 prompt

Comment: i got the solution without export statement it restores..Thanks anyway

Comment: `echo .dump | sqlite3 sourcedb.sqlite | sqlite3 targetdb.sqlite` seems to work on windows...

Comment: Why do I need to import a dump of the database? Can't I just use the database.db file to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

This should also work:

```
echo '.read export.sqlite3.sql' | sqlite3 my_database.sqlite3
```

One possible advantage over "`sqlite3 my_database.sqlite3 < export.sqlite3.sql`" is that SQLite's `.read` command might (now or in the future) be more advanced than just "read in all the text and execute it." It might do batching, which would reduce memory usage for large dumps.  I admit, though, that this is a pretty obscure and unlikely advantage. In all likelihood, `.read` simply reads each line from the input and executes it, just like the redirection and pipe operators.

Comment: Error: cannot open "export./home/ubuntu/trydatabase/newsql.sql"

using this command

Answer (score -3):

Use this for unix flavors.

press Ctrl+alt+T and write

```
sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/output.sqlite < /home/ubuntu/input.sql
```

It restore your database from input file.

Comment: What does 'Ctrl+alt+T' do on all Unix flavours?

Comment: It opens the terminal.